# Populate array of objects from namevaluecollection in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, namevaluecollection

I am new to C#. Here is a hard-coded thing I got working:

```
InputProperty grantNumber = new InputProperty();
grantNumber.Name = "udf:Grant Number";
grantNumber.Val = "571-1238";

Update update = new Update();
update.Items = new InputProperty[] { grantNumber };
```

Now I want to generalize this to support an indefinite number of items in the Update object and I came up with this but it fails to compile:

```
Update update = BuildMetaData(nvc);  //call function to build Update object
```

and the function itself here:

```
private Update BuildMetaData(NameValueCollection nvPairs)
{
    Update update = new Update();
    InputProperty[] metaData;       // declare array of InputProperty objects
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string key in nvPairs.Keys)
    {
        metaData[i] = new InputProperty();      // compiler complains on this line
        metaData[i].Name = "udf:" + key;
        foreach (string value in nvPairs.GetValues(key))
            metaData[i].Val = value;
    }
    update.Items = metaData;
    return update;      // return the Update object
}
```

Comment: What's the error message from the compiler?

Comment: Use of unassigned local variable 'metaData'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the size of your Items collection can vary, you should use a collection type like `List<T>` or `Dictionary<K,V>` instead of an array.

Comment: I tried to show at the beginning of my question how the update.Items needs to be assigned an array of InputProperty objects. I don't understand List and Dictionary yet.

Comment: It's a good time to learn, then.  These classes are used a lot.

Comment: Where can I find good introductory info on this syntax thing with the < > symbols as in List<T>? Every time I see syntax like Dictionary<K,V> or List<T> I fog over and I need a good intro.

Comment: The real short version is that the T, K, or V are just place holders for a type name like string or int.  When you put the type name in there, you're telling the class that it only works with items of that type.

Comment: I'd just like to add my humble concurrence - it's a terrific idea to learn about List<> and Dictionary<>. They are invaluable (and omnipresent) tools. Of the many places you can learn about generics - classes that use the <> construct - I like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions. Generics is moving to the top of my "study" stack. BUT - now I run into problem serializing my NameValueCollection through my web service:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663654/using-namevaluecollection-in-c-webservice-gives-not-xml-serializable-error

Answer (score 2):

For the current compiler error, you need to initialize the metaData array, like:

```
InputProperty[] metaData = new InputProperty[](nvPairs.Count);
```

Using linq you could:

```
private Update BuildMetaData(NameValueCollection nvPairs)
{
    Update update = new Update();
    update.Items = nvPairs.Keys
        .Select(k=> new InputProperty
                    {
                       Name = "udf:" + k,
                       Val = nvPairs[k] // or Values = nvPairs.GetValues(k)
                    }
         )
        .ToArray();
    return update;      // return the Update object
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I would've said... (if I had read the question in time!) ;-)

Comment: It should be "nvPairs.Count", though.

Comment: @Cerebrus fixed - if I am in the IDE, it is always one or the other :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, your InputProperty array is never initialized. If you change line 2 to this:

```
InputProperty[] metaData = new InputProperty[nvPairs.Count];
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared your array InputProperty[] metaData, you didn't initialize it.  So when you tried to access a member, it just doesn't exist, which is why you got the error you did.

As Joel recommended, I'd advise you to look at the collection types provided in System.Collections.Generic for something suitable.